# How to match a block of <li></li> using regexp

Tags: php, regex

how can I match a block of

```
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
```

no matter there is a blank line before or after the block
and enclose it in `<ul></ul>` tags using PHP's `preg_*`
functions.

Thank you for answer

Comment: [Regex, really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) PHP has got to have some sort of XML parser.

Comment: yes I want to use regex, hope someone would know

Comment: boundaries are new line characters \n

Comment: Stop wanting to use regex. They are the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: First I can't understand why someone downvotes this question
Second I'm conviced that this is possible using regexp
Third if you don't know answer, simply ignore it :)

Comment: It is possible to use regexp, but it is a bad idea. XML Parsers are better suited for this kind of problem

Comment: First: People are bored of people asking how to parse HTML with regex. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+regular+expression Second: It is possible to travel from London to Edinburgh by hopping while blindfold — that doesn't mean it is a good idea. Third: Aren't we past the stage of accusing people who say something is a bad idea of being ignorant?

Comment: This html is very short snippet in pure text comming from textarea. Who is accusing you you are an ignorant? I just asked you ignore the question if you don't know answer.

Comment: this is the only html comming from user everything else is deleted before.

Comment: Can we please stop bashing these kind of questions right away? If the content is well known, and the OP has a very specific need, **regexes are perfectly fine**. Stop linking that answer like it was the Holy Graal or something. It's a valid question: provide a valid answer or just move on.

Comment: That's right kemp, content is well known and task is very specific. Thanks.

Comment: Since you want to repair the HTML, consider using the [Tidy](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php) extension or http://HTMLPurifier.org

Comment: Thanks Gordon I don't want to use bunch of libraries and classes for simple things or write parser to parse invalid HTML

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is safe, controlled input, and you just got LIs with missing parent ULs, you can do:

```
preg_replace ( '#\s*(?:<li>.*</li>\s*)+#' , '<ul>$0</ul>', $input )
```

(You may want to add some `\n` to the replacement string before or after the UL.)

NOTE: This will fail if:

- There are any existing UL/OL lists in the content.
- There is anything other than whitespace between consecutive list items.
- Any of the LIs span multiple lines (the `.` excludes newline by default).
- There are any attributes on the LIs.
- Possibly some things I haven't considered.

Some of these can relatively easily be catered for, but I'm not going to - if you haven't got known specific content, you should be using a [real HTML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead.

The 'Regular' in Regular Expressions has a specific meaning, and full HTML is *not* a [Regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), so trying to handle all the intricacies of HTML with simple regex is liable to fail.
If you use a bad regex on user-supplied HTML, you may be introducing [HTML injection vulnerabilities](http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html) into your code.

Comment: Point #3 is trivial to fix, the rest falls under "controlled input".

Comment: It works :) There is no security issue for me input is fully controlled, thanks for your answer and links Peter.

Answer (score 1):

David already stated, that php got xml and html-parsers. However if you really want to use a regex, it probably would be something like:

```
preg_match('#<li>(.*?)</li>#', $string);
// Same thing
preg_match('#<li>(.*)</li>#U', $string);
```

Comment: Do you really need to escape the `/` when using `#` as regex boundaries?

Comment: Good point. Just tested it and it also works without escaping. I removed the slashes. Thanks :)

Comment: This works only if each `<li>..</li>` has a line to its self. If there are multiple list elements in on line it will match the whole line instead of each element for it's self.

Comment: No it works, if there are more <li>-tags on one line. That's why the `?` follows after the `*` or in the second version I used the  `U`-modifier to reverse the greediness. If you would leave that out, things would go like you're saying and `item1</li><li>item2` would be matches. That's not the case here.

Comment: there is always one LI pair per line. thank you very much faileN :)

Comment: You might want to add the `s` modifier to allow the dot to match newlines.

Comment: ivan73 does this answer solve your problem? If so, mark is as the solution, if not explain how it fails.

Comment: Look at the answer I've added then - that should do what you're after.

Comment: No, my *answer*, not that comment (which I'll go remove since I've linked to the core implementation in my answer). Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108812/how-to-match-a-block-of-li-li-using-regexp/3109512#3109512